# Cross compiling boost for m68k using bjam

Tags: c++, boost, cross-compiling, bjam

Using the docs, I run:

```
$ echo "using gcc : m68k : /opt/freescale/usr/local/gcc-4.2.125-eglibc-2.5.125/m68k-linux/bin/m68k-linux-gnu-g++ ;" >  tools/build/v2/user-config.jam
$ ./bootstrap.sh
$ ./bjam -d2 --toolset=gcc-m68k '-sBUILD=release static multi/single' link=static --prefix=/home/damann/coldfire/boost --layout=system --with-filesystem --with-system --with-thread --with-serialization --with-date_time install
```

Which gives the following errors:

```
error: toolset gcc initialization:
error: version 'm68k' requested but 'g++-m68k' not found and version '4.4.3' of default 'g++' does not match
error: initialized from
/home/damann/boost_1_48_0/tools/build/v2/build/toolset.jam:38: in toolset.using from module toolset
/home/damann/boost_1_48_0/tools/build/v2/build-system.jam:481: in process-explicit-toolset-requests from module build-system
/home/damann/boost_1_48_0/tools/build/v2/build-system.jam:562: in load from module build-system
/home/damann/boost_1_48_0/tools/build/v2/kernel/modules.jam:283: in import from module modules
/home/damann/boost_1_48_0/tools/build/v2/kernel/bootstrap.jam:142: in boost-build from module
/home/damann/boost_1_48_0/boost-build.jam:17: in module scope from module
```

It seems that the user-config is being ignored, although it is read (see it during `--debug-configuration`)

Answer (score 0):

Discovered that (at least on Linux) bjam also looks for a user-config.jam in the user's homedir - and I had one (that I had forgotten from an earlier build) - so that one was overriding my efforts.